# Switch to tab by file name in text editor

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I have multiple files open in different tabs in sublime text 3. Is there a way to switch to a tab by the name of the file that's open in it? If there's a different text editor that supports this, it'll be equally helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about sublime but in vscode you can type cmd/ctrl + p and type in the file name

Comment: This worked on sublime text as well, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the Goto Anything popup menu by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, the currently opened files will be listed at the top.

You can also select file tabs at different positions in the tab bar by using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>#</kbd>, where `#` is the file's position - <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> for the first file on the left, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> for the second from left, and so on. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd> to navigate through the tabs in order, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate through the stack of recently focused tabs.

All of these options are available under the **`Goto → Switch File`** menu. Some of the keyboard shortcuts may be different on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

[CudaText](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor (free) has the command "Find tab by title" in the plugin CudaExt. Command shows menu with the filter field. To install the plugin: "Plugins / Addon manager / Install".

[image: CudaText]